# Convert function weird behavior

Tags: julia

Why conversions never work from floating point to integer using `convert(type, x)` function?

When I use `int64(1.5)` it works fine returning 2, but when I try do `convert(Int64, 1.5)` it raises an InexactError. What is happening behind the scenes?

The [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/base/?highlight=convert#Base.convert) didn't please me.

Answer (score 3):

The reason that `convert` works this way is that it is a very general conversion function that is called implicitly by a lot of other functions. Because of this, it has been designed as a more or less lossless conversion to avoid any unpleasant surprises.

In Julia 0.3 you can use `iround`, `ifloor`, or `iceil` to round a floating point number to an integer in the specified way. In Julia 0.4, you should instead give the requested result type as the initial argument to `round`, `floor`, or `ceil`.